# How to make Fast forward animation on double tap like YouTube app

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-animation

I am using exoplayer for my video streaming needs for my app. I've implemented double tap to forward or rewind according to the x coordinate of the tap just like the YouTube app. However, I would also like to replicate the YouTube app's animation which plays when we double tap on the video player [animation-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQhPD.png).
I have Googled a lot but couldn't find any solution and couldn't think of a way to implement it.
I'm using Kotlin.

Comment: You need to provide extra information - some codes, what you have tried, etc.